# Delaying a repaint

Tags: java, awt, paint, keylistener, repaint

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Timer;

public class Spelare extends Applet implements KeyListener{

public int x = 240; 
public int y = 450;
public boolean skott = false; 

}

public void init() {
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setSize(500, 500);
    addKeyListener(this);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)  {

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(x, 450, 20, 15);

    if (skott == true) {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect (x, y, 3, 6);
    y-=1; 
    repaint();
    }
}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ) {
         if(x<470){
             x+=4;
             repaint();
         }
     }

     else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT ) {
    if (x>10) {
         x-=4;
         repaint();
     }
     }
     if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE ) {
         skott = true; 

     }
     }
```

This is my first time using Stack Overflow.

I'm wondering how I can get the repaint on the y-variable to be delayed. Because when I press space the skott-variable becomes true and it repaints so fast the rectangle is on the screen for the duration of one frame approximately. I'm very new to Java so I'm not fully certain I'm doing everything correctly.

I was thinking maybe I could use a timer to make the repaint sleep. But I have no clue how I should approach it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the thread to sleep, just add `Thread.sleep(n)`, where `n` is the amount in milliseconds you want to sleep, to your code right before the `repaint()` call. Note however this is has major implications. Since this is (presumably) done on your main thread, it will actually stop the applet for those `n` milliseconds.